# Some JPanel's backgrounds fade when I interact with page

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

As i wrote in the title, I've this problem with JPanel. 
My page is structured as a mainJPanel, another JPanel inside the main (where I paint a background) and some component added to this background panel.

Everytime I interact with something (for example i click a button) the background of the components fade to a lighter version of themselves.

I really can't figure out why.

mainPanel have setOpaque(false) and setLayout(null);

backgroundPanel have setOpaque(false) and setLayout(null) (i painted the background when i create the class backgroundPanel that extends JPanel, with an override of the method paintComponent);

all the components that becomes lighter have setOpaque(true) and setLayout(null);
the background of this components are a custom grey (rgb(232,232,232)).

Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

Using `setOpaque(false)` should not cause a problem (ie. JLabels are non opaque). It sounds like a painting problem when using transparent colors.

Check out [Background With Transparency](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/31/backgrounds-with-transparency/) for an explanation of the problem and a couple of solutions.